# In which place interrupts can interrupt function in C?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling, spinlock

I'm writing code in ISO C90, which forbids mixed declarations and code.
So I have something like this:

```
int function(int something)
{
    int foo, ret;
    int bar = function_to_get_bar();
    some_typedef_t foobar = get_this_guy(something);

    spin_lock_irqsave(lock);

    /*
    Here is code that does a lot of things
    */

    spin_unlock_irqrestore(lock);

    return ret;
}
```

The question is if hardware or software interrupt happens, in which place it can interrupt my function, can it happen also in the middle of variable declaration?

Why I ask this is because I need that this function is not interrupted by interrupts. I want to use spin_lock_irqsave() to ensure that, but I was wondering if interrupt could interrupt my function in variable declarations?

Answer (score 5):

Interrupts are highly hardware platform specific. But there is no "variable declaration" in the code the processor runs. The variables are just places in memory (or in registers, if the compiler so chooses) that are predetermined.

If you mean assigning to variables then yes, in general interrupts can happen. If you need `function_to_get_bar()` not to be interrupted and `spin_lock_irqsave(lock);` guarantees it won't, then just move the assignment inside it.

```
int function(int something)
{
    int foo, ret;
    int bar; // This is declaration, just for the compiler
    some_typedef_t foobar;

    spin_lock_irqsave(lock);

    bar = function_to_get_bar(); // This is assignment, will actually run some code on the CPU
    foobar = get_this_guy(something);

    /*
    Here is code that does a lot of things
    */

    spin_unlock_irqrestore(lock);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Of course it will be completed before entering the lock, but that was not the point. The values come from functions and interrupts may happen while they are called, unless locked. Interrupts may affect the result of the functions.

Comment: Just a side note: On SMP systems the interrupts will come to the rest CPUs still, but code running on this certain CPU will be not interrupted. And we have to remember (especially in the functions like *1) spin_lock(), 2) do_smth(), 3) spin_unlock(), and 4) return*) we protect data access, not the code itself!